# Keycloak custom authenticator script - how to get the access token or external idp token of the user within the script context?

Tags: javascript, authentication, keycloak

I'm trying to implement an Authenticator Execution Script in Keycloak 6.0.X, which retrieves an external IDP token for the user and transforms it before adding it back into the jwt/access token. The script runs asa 'Post Login Flow' Execution.

I'm so far unable to access either the user access token or the external IDP token directly within the script.

```
    /*
    * Template for JavaScript based authenticator's.
    * See org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.ScriptBasedAuthenticatorFactory
    */

    // import enum for error lookup
    AuthenticationFlowError = Java.type("org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowError");

    /**
    * An example authenticate function.
    *
    * The following variables are available for convenience:
    * user - current user {@see org.keycloak.models.UserModel}
    * realm - current realm {@see org.keycloak.models.RealmModel}
    * session - current KeycloakSession {@see org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession}
    * httpRequest - current HttpRequest {@see org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest}
    * script - current script {@see org.keycloak.models.ScriptModel}
    * authenticationSession - current authentication session {@see org.keycloak.sessions.AuthenticationSessionModel}
    * LOG - current logger {@see org.jboss.logging.Logger}
    *
    * You one can extract current http request headers via:
    * httpRequest.getHttpHeaders().getHeaderString("Forwarded")
    *
    * @param context {@see org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowContext}
    */

function authenticate(context) {

    var username = user ? user.username : "anonymous";
    LOG.info(script.name + " trace auth for: " + username);

    var federatedIdentity = session.users().getFederatedIdentities(user, realm);
    LOG.info(script.name + " federatedIdentity= " + federatedIdentity);

    var token = federatedIdentity.getToken();

    var authShouldFail = false;
    if (authShouldFail) {

        context.failure(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
        return;
    }

    context.success();
}
```

I'm able to successfully get the FederatedIdentityModel which according to the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/FederatedIdentityModel.html)
should have a getToken() method however the script fails at this method call with the following error:

> TypeError: federatedIdentity.getToken is not a function in eval

I've tried using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(session)` to see what fields and methods are available on these variables but it turns our they're not Javascript Objects at all..

> TypeError: org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession@2f2807cd is not an Object in eval

More digging reveals:

`session instanceof Object` returns `false`
while `typeof session` returns `'object'`

Any ideas or inspiration would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`getFederatedIdentities` returns a Set, so you need:

```
var federatedIdentity = session.users().getFederatedIdentities(user, realm).toArray()[0];
```